# Unable to convert string to date in Python

Tags: python, date

```
from datetime import date


class student:
     def __init__ (self, firstname, lastname, number, birth):
         self.firstname = str(firstname)
         self.lastname = str(lastname)
         self.number = int(number)
         self.birthdate = date.fromisoformat(birth)
         self.note = int(0)
         self.kurs = str()

     def __repr__ (self):
         return '{firstname:' + str (self.firstname) + ', lastname:' \
                + str (self.lastname) + ',' 'number:' \
                + self.number + ',' 'birth:' \
                + self.birthdate + '}'

     def grade_entry (self):
         input ("coursename:")
         input ("coursegrade:")


     def put_entry(self):
         print(student.grade_entry())



o = student ('My', 'Name', '123456', '01-01-2000')
print(o)
student.grade_entry()
student.put_entry()
```

The following is wrong i cant resolve it i hope one person can help me.

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'
```

By the way can you tell me something. So if I write a few course names in def `grade_entry`, he should give it to me in the next function

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are using `date.fromisoformat` but `'01-01-2000'` is not of this format.

---

The following will work:

```
import datetime


self.birthdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(birth, '%d-%m-%Y').date()
```

---

On another note, your `__repr__` is also wrong. Make sure to cast `self.number` and `self.birthdate` (i.e. `str(self.number)` and `str(self.birthdate)`):

```
 def __repr__ (self):
     return '{firstname:' + str(self.firstname) + ', lastname:' \
            + str(self.lastname) + ',' 'number:' \
            + str(self.number) + ',' 'birth:' \
            + str(self.birthdate) + '}'
```

---

Finally, you are incorrectly calling the class instead of the created instance.

Instead of

```
o = student ('My', 'Name', '123456', '01-01-2000')
print(o)
student.grade_entry()
student.put_entry()
```

you should use:

```
o = student ('My', 'Name', '123456', '01-01-2000')
print(o)
o.grade_entry()
o.put_entry()
```

Also, `put_entry` should call `self.grade_entry()` instead of `student.grade_entry()`.

Comment: i will test it now.

Comment: so i add this but the error is the same i have write a birth like '01-01-2000'

Comment: @anfaenger_tester It works fine for me. You have probably missed something.

Comment: i copy and paste your code.. it doesn't work .. what am I doing wrong

Comment: Wait i forgot to delete from datetime...

Now this is the error :
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: @anfaenger_tester Replace `self.birthdate = date.fromisoformat(birth)` with `self.birthdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(birth, '%d-%m-%Y').date()`

Comment: Yes i changed it

Comment: Thanks i will ask another question

Comment: @anfaenger_tester I have seen your other question. The solution is already in this answer. I updated my answer to make it more clear for you.